# React native - rendering a list of inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Edit: Thanks guys, wow I feel dumb.

For a React-Native component, I am trying to render a list of input boxes. For example, the code below should render three input boxes. I simply want it such that when I type the letter "A" into the first box, the screen renders that "A" has been typed, just like your typical input box onChangeText().

However, I'm having a hard time getting this to work -- I don't think any of my state is actually getting stored. When I type "A" in a box, nothing shows up on the screen.

Pardon me if I'm missing something obvious, I'm fairly new to React and React-Native in general. I searched pretty thoroughly for a previously answered question -- I saw something regarding React but it was rendering HTML so I'm not sure if it was applicable. Thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      texts: ['', '', ''],
    };
  }


  renderInputs() {
    return this.state.texts.map((text, i) => {
      return <Input 
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.rerenderOnChange(text, i)}
        value={this.state.texts[i]}
        placeholder='Email'
        placeholderTextColor='white'
        autoCapitalize='none'
        inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
      />
    });
  }

  rerenderOnChange(text, index) {
    texts = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.texts.length; i++) {
      if (i == index) {
        texts.push(text);
      } else {
        texts.push(this.state.texts[i]);
      }
    }
    this.state.texts = texts;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.view}>

        { this.renderInputs() }

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few simple changes and it's working

Like -

```
this.state.texts = texts;
```

to

```
this.setState({ texts });
```

and

```
texts = []
```

to

```
const texts = []
```

or

```
let texts = []
```

Please find the working example below - 
https://snack.expo.io/H18lWDM84

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `this.state.texts = texts;`

use `this.setState({texts : texts})` in your `rerenderOnChange()` method

**Please note :** Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.